# CSS Transition from top to bottom and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, css

my transition is not working.

I have this HTML:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#drawer {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  /* This transition is not working */
  transition: all 0.5 ease-in;
}

#drawer.closed {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  /* This transition is not working */
  transition: all 0.5 ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="drawer" class="closed">
    <p>THIS SHOULD SLIDE</p>
    <p>THIS SHOULD SLIDE</p>
    <p>THIS SHOULD SLIDE</p>
    <p>THIS SHOULD SLIDE</p>
    <p>THIS SHOULD SLIDE</p>
    <p>THIS SHOULD SLIDE</p>
    <p>THIS SHOULD SLIDE</p>
    <p>THIS SHOULD SLIDE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have prepared the example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hr6nvL08/8/). It should help explain my question, but there are some stipulations I would like to add:

- I would like to use pure CSS to make the transition.
- The Drawer Div doesn't have a fixed height, which would make it a lot easier.
- The Drawer should come in from the top and stop when top meets top.

Is this possible with pure CSS or do I have to use JS?

Comment: You can't transition to/from `auto`.

Comment: Do you want to open it when a button is clicked?

Comment: @Konrud yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long trial and error period, I have determined that this can't be done with pure CSS. I will use the [JQuery SlideDown](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) function to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with visibility attr:

```
#drawer {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  /* This transition is working now*/
  visibility: visible;
  transition: visibility 2s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 1;
}

#drawer.closed {
  bottom: 0;
  /* This transition is working now*/
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 2s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: This is not an opacity/visibility issue. It's a height issue.

Comment: This is an alternative way of doing what Daechir needs. I haven't seen your working answer Paulie

Comment: No it's not. He wants a sliding down option which this is not. What he needs is javascript.